# Handling with iframe on a webpage using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I would like to use my script to grab some data from charts on investing.com, but first I need to prepare chart before data **scraping** (chart maximizing. switching on candle bars).
I know that needed buttons are located inside iframe element. Unfortunately my script cannot find these elements. I tried locate iframe by "frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it" but script still cannot find iframe and thus required elements. My code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import visibility_of_element_located

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
options = Options()
options.headless = False
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)
action = ActionChains(driver)


def cookie_handling():
    driver.get("https://www.investing.com/equities/inpost-sa-as-chart")
    COOKIE_BUTTON = By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler'
    cookie_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(COOKIE_BUTTON))
    cookie_button.click()
    print("Cookie handling finalized")


def chart_preparing():
    scroll_down = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body')
    for i in range(19):
        scroll_down.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)

    FRAME_LOCATOR = By.CLASS_NAME, "fwh mp0 no-overflow"
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(FRAME_LOCATOR))

    FULLSCREEN_LOCATOR = By.CLASS_NAME, "button fullscreen iconed"
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until((EC.element_to_be_clickable(FULLSCREEN_LOCATOR))).click()

    CANDLE_LOCATOR = By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/span[1]"
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until((EC.element_to_be_clickable(CANDLE_LOCATOR))).click()


cookie_handling()
chart_preparing()
```

I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Can you add the html contain the Iframe? Just cut away the excess. And for readability, maybe add a //problem HERE in the code segment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are 3 iframes there and all your iframe locators are wrong.
Also other locator should be improved.
Please try this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import visibility_of_element_located

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
options = Options()
options.headless = False
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)
action = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)


def cookie_handling():
    driver.get("https://www.investing.com/equities/inpost-sa-as-chart")
    COOKIE_BUTTON = By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler'
    cookie_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(COOKIE_BUTTON))
    cookie_button.click()
    print("Cookie handling finalized")


def chart_preparing():
    scroll_down = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body')
    for i in range(19):
        scroll_down.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)

    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@seamless and not( @class)]"))

    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@seamless and @class]"))
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@id,'tradingview')]"))

    FULLSCREEN_LOCATOR = By.CLASS_NAME, "button fullscreen iconed"
    wait.until((EC.element_to_be_clickable(FULLSCREEN_LOCATOR))).click()

    CANDLE_LOCATOR = By.XPATH, "//span[@title='Candles']"
    wait.until((EC.element_to_be_clickable(CANDLE_LOCATOR))).click()


cookie_handling()
chart_preparing()
```

Comment: There's no need to declare all those instances of `WebDriverWait(driver, 10)`. Declare the first, assign it to a variable, and then reuse it. Scrolling down using arrow keys is not going to be consistent or very efficient. It would be better to scroll to a particular element.

Comment: @JeffC you are right, I fixed that.